# Suspected scope issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am learning how to code and working on a Hack Reactor puzzle (see below). *I don't understand why the else part of my function block does not work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?*

> Write a function called `getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty`.
>
> Given an object and a key, `getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty` returns
>   an array containing all the elements of the array located at the given
>   key that are equal to ten.
>
> Notes:
>
> - If the array is empty, it should return an empty array.
> - If the array contains no elements are equal to 10, it should return an empty array.
> - If the property at the given key is not an array, it should return an empty array.
> - If there is no property at the key, it should return an empty array.

Example:

```
var obj = { key: [1000, 10, 50, 10] };
var output = getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, 'key'); 
console.log(output); // > --> [10, 10]
```

**My Solution:**

```
var obj = {
  key: '[1000, 10, 50, 10]'
};

function getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, key) {
  if (typeof Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
    for (let key in obj) {
      tenArray = obj.key = obj[key].filter( element => element === 10);
    }
  } else {
    tenArray = obj.key = [];
  }
  return tenArray;
}

console.log(getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, 'key'))
```

Final Solution

```
var obj = {
  key: [1000, 10, 50, 10]
};

function getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, key) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
     tenArray = obj[key].filter( element => element === 10);
  } else {
    tenArray = [];
  }
  return tenArray;
}

console.log(getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, 'key'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only isArray to check for array, no need of `typeof` here.

```js
var obj = {
  key: '[1000, 10, 50, 10]'
};
console.log(Array.isArray(obj.key)) // false
console.log(typeof Array.isArray(obj.key)) // 'boolean'
console.log(Boolean(typeof Array.isArray(obj.key))) // true
```

Array at 'key' value should be declared without single-quotes, else it will be treated as string.

```js
var obj = {
  key: [1000, 10, 50, 10]
};
console.log(Array.isArray(obj.key)) // true
```

There is no need for a `for ..in` here as the key is already known. Also no need to modify obj.key I guess.

```
  if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
     tenArray = obj[key].filter( element => element === 10);
  }
```

Comment: Sabith, thanks. This indeed solved my mistake and stayed as close to my initial thinking as possible. I do appreciate the alternative solution, which is better and helps me to think through the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Obj[key] is not declared as an array in your code but as a string. You can also do much simpler to meet your requirements :

```js
var obj = {
  key: [1000, 10, 50, 10]
};

function getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, key) {
  if (obj[key] && obj[key] instanceof Array) {
     return obj[key].filter( element => element === 10);
  }  
  return [];
}

console.log(getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, 'key'));
```

Comment: This code is definitely better, Bertrand. Thank you for looking at my problem and pointing out a better solution. It helps me a lot.

Comment: I can only accept one answer it seems. For the purpose of learning, I think Sabith's answer is a slightly better fit. I do appreciate your feedback though.

Comment: Ok. Didn't notice :) No problem

Answer (score 0):

Filter the array:

```
var obj = {
  key: [1000, 10, 50, 10]
}

function getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, key) {
  var tens = []
  if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
    tens = obj[key].filter(function(el) {
      return (10 === el)
    })
  }
  return tens
}

var tensArray = getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, 'key')

console.log(tensArray)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Dan. I have looked at all suggestions and learned a great deal. Finally, settled for the simplification of my initial train of thought pointed out to me by Sabith. I have edited my post and closed the issue. Really appreciate all the feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you set `obj.key` instead of `obj[key]` in the `else` part of your function.

Comment: Thank you Lorenz, that is absolutely right. I realize I have made this error before.

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with the issue. It simply change obj.key value to the returned array (that may not be a desired behaviour however).